# Is TLS gRPC distinguishable from TLS HTTP2?

Tags: security, protocol-buffers, grpc, network-protocols, grpc-go

Or do they appear identical to a potentially hostile middle-box?
Notwithstanding profiling of traffic flows which may out gRPC.

TLS/JA3 fingerprints may also be a problem, but assume they are handled in some way.

Documentation doesn't address this aspect.

Answer (score 0):

gRPC (if we ignore exotic transports) is implemented on top of HTTP/2, so: gRPC *is* HTTP/2, but not all HTTP/2 is gRPC.

If you need to distinguish whether something is gRPC:

- you can check the content-type
- gRPC *in some scenarios* (streaming) has the notable rare feature where response data starts *before* the request has completed (from an intermediary perspective this is important, as it means you need independent read/write loops - you can't just proxy all the request, then proxy all the response)

Answer (score 0):

From the perspective of a middle box, I believe a generic TLS record that holds gRPC should be indistinguishable from a generic TLS record that holds some other HTTP2 traffic. That said, if the middle box profiles how the TLS handshake is negotiated (especially when versions < 1.3 are used), the middle box may be able to guess that gRPC is being used under the TLS layer.